# KSP - How to consolidate module results into a file

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

I am looking to utilize KSP to generate a comprehensive list of feature flags across various modules in my project, including the *'app', 'module1', 'module2'*, up to *'moduleN'.*

Currently, I have a code processor in place that gathers each @FeatureFlag annotation, and the KSP processor serves as a dependency for each module.

Here is a snapshot of how feature flags are collected in each module:

**Module 1:**

```
#build/generated/ksp/main/kotlin/package

internal val featuresFlags : Set<FeatureFlag> = setOf(settingsFeatureFlag, profileFeatureFlag)
```

**Module 2:**

```
#build/generated/ksp/main/kotlin/package

internal val featuresFlags : Set<FeatureFlag> = setOf(fingerprintFeatureFlag)
```

**Module N**

```
#build/generated/ksp/main/kotlin/package

internal val featuresFlags : Set<FeatureFlag> = setOf(0...N)
```

Now, I'm seeking a way to consolidate these individual results into a single variable or use case. The desired outcome is as follows:

**Feature flag module**

```
internal val featuresFlags : Set<FeatureFlag> = setOf(settingsFeatureFlag, profileFeatureFlag, fingerprintFeatureFlag, ...) # contact all modules result
```

I am also grappling with a potential limitation in KSP -[ksp-issue](https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/1075#issuecomment-122265891).  Also, when I try to write outcome out of each module I get

> [ksp] java.lang.IllegalStateException: requested path is outside the
> bounds of the required directory

Comment: if you put a small project to show how these works, like a "reproducer" ? it may help people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the options I have tried myself, just spitting ideas.

Have you tried to pass the target build directory as KSP argument to the submodules?

Try adding this to the app module gradle:

```
tasks.withType<com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspTask> {
    options.add(SubpluginOption("targetOutputDir", "build/generated/ksp/debug/kotlin"))
}
```

Alternatively, after each ksp task is done:

This will append directory as command line argument

```
tasks.withType<com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspTask> {
    commandLineArgumentProviders.add(CommandLineArgumentProvider { listOf("app/build/generated/ksp/debug/kotlin") })
```

Or

```
tasks.withType<com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspTask> {
    doLast {
        val targetFile = File("${projectDir}/app/build/generated/ksp/debug/kotlin", "FeatureFlags.kt")
        targetFile.outputStream().use {output ->
            outputs.files.forEach {
                //copy content
                //append to target file
                output.write(it.readBytes())
            }
        }

    }
}
```